# Find Variable based on today's date/Day of the week

Tags: excel, vlookup

Can i ask vba to grab the column that contains the word Wed. (because today is 5/13/15: Wednesday) then Copy that whole column and paste it somewhere else.

Comment: Yes you can. But you would need to show what you have tried and explain where you got stuck in trying to achieve this.

Comment: You can use format function to get the day abbreviation: **format(now(),"ddd")** . This will  returns  Wed and from there you can use Find function to search the columns header.

Comment: my purpose is to pull the information from the Column with tday's day. so I know the employees' schedule. from there I need to copy that column's to another sheet

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
=TEXT(NOW();"DD/MM/YYYY:DDDD")
```